# Cannot use software update "SoftwareUpdateNoticationManager quit unexpectedly", in MacOS 10.15.7 on macbook pro. Softwareupdate crashes everytime

Tags: macos, catalina, software-update, crash, error

**About My Mac:**

MacBook Pro 11,3 2014, MacOS Catalina macOS 10.15.7 (19H524)

**Issues:**

When trying to update MacOS Software using systempreferences or via the notification center Install popup I get 3 consistent error messages after a softwareupdate and system preferences crash.

1. *com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice (System Preferences) quit unexpectedly.[[image: com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice (System Preferences) quit unexpectedly1]
2. *Preferences Error: There was an error in Software Update preferences.*
   [image: Preferences Error: There was an error in Software Update preferences MacOS Image]
3. *SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager quit unexpectedly.*
   [image: SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager quit unexpectedly MacOS 10.15.7 error]
   [image: Problem Report for SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager]

**Things i've tried:**

1. Creating a new user account and trying software update. NOTE: THIS WORKS!. So the issue must be in the users home folder.
2. Downloading and installing software updates via command line with in the malfunctioning user account via `softwareupdate --install --all`  NOTE: THIS WORKS ALSO!
3. Reinstalling MacOS on top of my currenct install without erasing MacintoshHD. This DOESN'T SOLVE THE ISSUE! ISSUE REMAINS PRESENT AFTER INSTALL!
4. Backing up via Time-Machine, doing a full clean install, and then restoring from time maching. NOTE: THIS DOESN'T SOLVE THE ISSUE! ISSUE REMAINS AFTER CLEAN INSTALL AND RESTORE!

**Issues that may have caused this:**

1. I read some post on a random mac forum about eliminating notifications for macOS software update. I entered a command that I am fairly certain modified a plist file for mac os. I don't know what command I used or what plist file it modified. I'm hoping it is just as easy as finding the plist file and removing it hoping mac os recreates a default plist file.

**LOGS:**

[FULL LOG REPORT OF com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice (System Preferences) shared on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yiAxe3tj)

[FULL LOG REPORT OF "SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager" shared on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0g52chBh)

**My Question:**

How can I fix this so that softwareupdate properly works on my current user account with my current mac os install?

Comment: Can you share the full crash report via www.PasteBin.com?

Comment: @pion Yes, I just added pastebin links with full logs to the original post. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: Same issue here on Big Sur. Updated to Monterey and still same issue. What can be done?

Comment: I had to do a clean install and NOT restore with time machine, because restoring with time machine recreates the problem. I instead used carbon copy cloner to create a backup, and then manually transfered files from my backup to my desktop. I spent many hours redownloading and registering all of my applications. Thats the god aweful solution.

Comment: You can also user the free app called "super duper" to make a full cloned backup of your drive then reinstall manually.